# Logstash: convert lambert to latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby, logstash

I am working on a project where I have in my input data some coordinates in lambert. i would like to convert these coordinates in latitude and longitude. I found on internet a function in ruby to do it: https://github.com/yageek/lambert-ruby . However, I don't think I can use it in logstash. Then, do you know if there is a function or a plugin in logstash.

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: If the conversion can be transformed in ruby code (I have no idea how difficult it is), you can use the logstash [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) with this code. Or you can wrap the gem you have linked in a custom logstash filter and use this filter. You can find a guide on creating Logstash filter [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html) and examples [there](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/)

Comment: This is what I did :) !

Comment: If it works, you can answer your own question, so that other people with same problem can use it too.